# On item click, make other items visible

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I have this in my `activity_main_drawer.xml`:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/menu1" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="menu 1" />
        <item android:id="@+id/submenu1" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="submenu 1" android:visible="false" />
</group>
```

I want when someone click `menu1` to change `submenu1` *android:visible* to **true**.

I tried with:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == menu1) {
            R.id.submenu1..setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

But I get **Cannot Resolve Method setVisibility(int)**. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing:

```
findViewById(R.id.submenu1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

`R.id.submenu1` is just a number, but you can use that to find the actual widget (and then do things to that object).

Comment: Sounds like it didn't find the widget..
Take a look at this answer on how to debug NullPointerExceptions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/218510/1715829